# Ventrilo on VMware View workstation

Tags: vmware, vdi, ventrilo

I've got a VMware View 5.1 environment I'm working with. To test some VOIP type efforts I thought I'd try to connect to my friends ventrilo server.
With the teradici sound driver on the VDI machine I can listen to audio (youtube, mp3, etc) and record audio (sound recorder), but it's not working in Vent. Even just using the test button with any of the codecs listed, nothing. However the monitor function does react to microphone input.

Any help is appreciated,
Puzzled